# Every entry to website will forward first to some page

Tags: proxy

I want to do in my office to all workers that if someone enters a website, he goes first to some url that will save his URL that he trying to go and then move him to his URL.

How can I do it? Via hosts file or is there another way to do it via router or something?

Or where can I read about it? Or how it's called? :)

Comment: Sounds like you want a captive portal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is Internet Monitoring.  Generally, you set up a server with software designed to do this.

I'm NOT making an endorsement, but the first one that comes to mind, simp;ly because it's the most recent I've seen, is iPrism.  http://www.edgewave.com/products/web_security/

You can find a bunch more here.  http://www.google.com/search?q=internet+usage+monitpring&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=

That said, this question should be moved to ServerFault.com because it is NOT a programming issue, unless you intend to write an Internet Monitoring system yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a transparent proxy, (or not so transparent but mandatory) e.g. squid they often provide ways of allowing you to rewrite URLs. With squid you can set a `url_rewrite_program`:

```
url_rewrite_program /usr/local/bin/redirector.pl
```

You then write a redirector program, e.g. this proof-of concept:

```
my %approved;

while (<>) {
         chomp;
         my @parts = split;
         my ($url, $ip, $ident, $method, $keypairs) = @parts;

         if (defined $approved{$ip}) {
           # We've seen them before
           print "$url\n";
         }
         else {
            # Not seen before
            # You *will* need to urlencode $url for this
            print "302:http://internal.site/page?dest=$url\n"; 
            $approved{$ip} = 1;
         }
}
```

Then all you need to do is implement `http://internal.site/page` so that it shows your message and either has a time based or click based redirect back to the url it was passed as `dest`.

Probably what you would want to do is use `%approved` to record the last time you saw a request from that machine and have a time out. You might also want to consider using lower level things than just the IP address, e.g. look up MAC address and switch ports.

Comment: what I need to do? install some software on my worker computer? I dont understand... :\

Comment: You need to install it on/near the core infrastructure in your office. Probably what you want to do is make your edge router(s) send all port 80 outbound traffic via one or more squid proxy server(s). You would need an exception for the proxy server(s) itself though obviously. You won't need to touch your desktops at all for this.